# One select list consisting of two classes

Tags: c#, selectlist

I have 3 classes

```
public class A
{
    public decimal id {get; set;}
    public virtual B? BNavigation {get; set;};
    public virtual C? CNavigation {get; set;};
}

public class B
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set;}
    [...]

}

public class C
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set;}
    [...]
}
```

I try example above, string concatenation, tried to do it with LINQ.
I realized that I need to do this through an auxiliary class.

And i want to make SelectList by class A

Example:

```
ViewData["A"] = new SelectList( A,"Id", "BNavigation.title - CNavigation.title");
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried to far

Comment: I think you forget using class C! read again and valid question.

Answer (score 0):

I want this post to be closed, because i found block of code which decide my problem

```
ViewBag.PackageId = db.Packages.Where(p => p.status == "A")
  .Select(p => new SelectListItem
  {
         Text = p.u_package_id + "-" + p.package_nme,
         Value = p.u_package_id.ToString()
  });
```